# Cannot build docker image (ASP.NET Core )

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

I have asp.net core solution, that contains 3 projects.

I want to deploy it to the docker container.

Here is how the solution looks like

[image]

Here is my Dockerfile

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "tooseeweb.dll"]
```

But when I run docker build
I got this in console

> Skipping project "/TooSeeWeb.Core/TooSeeWeb.Core.csproj" because it
>   was not found.
>
> Skipping project
>   "/TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure/TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure.csproj" because it
>   was not found.
>
> > > MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. Switch: TooSeeWeb.csproj
>
> Error: ResponseItem.ErrorDetail[code=1,message=The command '/bin/sh -c
>   dotnet build "TooSeeWeb.csproj" -c Release -o /app' returned a
>   non-zero code: 1] Failed to deploy ' Dockerfile:
>   TooSeeWeb/Dockerfile': The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet build
>   "TooSeeWeb.csproj" -c Release -o /app' returned a non-zero code: 1

Where can be a problem?

**UPDATE**

Structure of folders of my solution

```
TooSeeWeb
 |- aspnet-core(folder)
    |-TooSeeWeb (folder)
      |- TooSeeWeb.sln
      |- TooSeeWeb
         |-Dockerfile
         |- TooSeeWeb.csproj
      |- TooSeeWeb.Core(folder)
         |- TooSeeWeb.Core.csproj
      |- TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure(folder)
         |- TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure.csproj
```

**UPDATE2**

I move dockerfile in the same folder with sln (it's one folder up)

Now my docker file looks like this

```
    ROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln ./
COPY TooSeeWeb/*.csproj ./TooSeeWeb/
COPY TooSeeWeb.Core/*.csproj ./TooSeeWeb.Core/
COPY TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure/.*csproj ./TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure/
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app/TooSeeWeb
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "tooseeweb.dll"]
```

But I got error

> Step 4/14 : COPY *.sln ./
>   COPY failed: no source files were specified

Answer (score 2):

The COPY command doesn't reproduce the same folder structure in the target folder, so your .csproj files are all in the same folder and the references are broken.
Try adding

```
COPY TooSeeWeb.Core/*.csproj ./TooSeeWebCore/
COPY TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure/*.csproj ./TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure/
```

**Update:**
An example folder structure for a solution, with projects in subfolders

```
src
 |-my.sln
 |-Dockerfile
 |-Web (folder)
   |-web.csproj
 |-Core (folder)
   |-core.csproj
 |-Infrastructure (folder)
   |-infrastructure.csproj
```

The Dockerfile would be

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln ./
COPY Web/*.csproj ./Web/
COPY Core/*.csproj ./Core/
COPY Infrastructure/.*csproj ./Infrastructure/
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
WORKDIR /app/Web
RUN dotnet build
```

**Update 2**
If there is no solution file then I think you need to dotnet restore each project individually

```
COPY Web/*.csproj ./Web/
COPY Core/*.csproj ./Core/
COPY Infrastructure/.*csproj ./Infrastructure/
RUN dotnet restore ./Web/Web.csproj
RUN dotnet restore ./Core/Core.csproj
RUN dotnet restore ./Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj
etc
```

Comment: `Step 4/12 : COPY TooSeeWeb.Core/*.csproj ./TooSeeWeb.Core/


Error: ResponseItem.ErrorDetail[code=<null>,message=COPY failed: no source files were specified]
Failed to deploy '<unknown> Dockerfile: TooSeeWeb/Dockerfile': COPY failed: no source files were specified`

Go this now

Comment: So the Dockerfile is in the TooSeeWeb folder so you still have a problem with relative references. I have updated my answer to show one possible solution or you can keep your Dockerfile where it is and adjust the paths.

Comment: It not helps, or I do smth not right. I updated the question with a tree of solution

Comment: Look at my comment and updated answer. Move your Dockerfile up one folder and look at the structure of the Dockerfile I gave. Copy each project separately into a subfolder in the target. Be sure to add WORKDIR /app/TooSeeWeb before dotnet build.

Comment: I tried, docker cannot find `.sln`

I updated question